# What is Classical History... in Italian?

Tags: translation

I am trying to determine what the Italian and classical Latin (Roman) are for the following words:

> Ancient History 
> Classical History

I've tried various online translators and Google searches, but not being proficient in either, I can't be absolutely sure if what I have found is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie mille Charo. And for the additional information, well worth a study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see at Encyclopedia Treccani that one uses the expressions [*storia antica*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/scienze_sociali_e_storia/storia/storia_antica/) for Ancient History
and [*storia classica*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/domenico-bandini_%28Dizionario-Biografico%29/) for Classical History. In the last link, you have to look for the expression in the biography of Domenico Bandini, a medieval author that wrote several books: one of them was a biographical dictionary an important part of which was devoted to Classical History.

Answer (score 2):

"Storia antica" is used for Ancient History, meaning the history before the Middle Ages in general. I dont't see "storia classica" often, not to say never: it's much more likely to read "storia romana" and "storia greca", for the ancient Roman and Greek periods of course. "Antichità classica" as an expression matching closely "Classical Antiquity" is often used, though.